# MYSQL Max row limit

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm stuck on mysql query which doesn't want to get result more than ~2800 rows (more or less).

I get connected to the db remotely:

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql://myserver;port=3306;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8', 'my_user', 'my_pass',
            array(
                PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => "100",
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
            )); 
        ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 30);
        ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 30);
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 30);
```

Here is what the query looks like :

```
$result = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM CONTACT WHERE name LIKE 'whatever' OR phone LIKE 'whatever2' OR phone LIKE 'whatever3'... ");
```

I got results untill the ~2800 row, it means the query get stopped at the 2800 row then doesn't care of the rest of the row even if they match the query.

Please help, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: By adding limit and offset to your query you still can get all the results

Comment: What kind of thing is 'whatever'?

Comment: But then you must also order the results to ensure the pagination is correct.

Comment: Are you ***certain*** that there are more than 2800 rows that match?  Have you ***tested*** that assumption?  If so, how?  What do you get if you replace `*` with `COUNT(*)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comments!
The problem was that I wasn't at the good database.. I have duplicated it and was pointing on the wrong one, sorry for my newbeness =)

There is no row limitin at the good one =)

Thank you again!